# Javascript custom sort by String attribute

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm looking to do a custom sort on an `array` based on one of its attributes. So for example if I have a `person` object:

`var person = {name:""};`

and I want to sort on `name` but not alphabetically. So if I have:

- Tim
- Mike
- Jen
- Ashley

but I want this to be sorted:

- Mike
- Ashley
- Tim
- Jen

How would I accomplish this? I know I can use a function to compare:

```
array.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x < y) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (x > y) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

But this would result in an alphabetical sort. Then I thought if there was a way to assign a numerical value to each potential name (I will have a known, limited set) then to try that, but I'm not sure it's the correct approach. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: but how are they sorted then?

Comment: take an object with the names as key and a number as value (maybe without zero) if you have unknown names (this names can be sorted to start, end or any other place) and sort by this value or take a default value, like `Infinity` or `-Infinity`. please have a look to the duplicate target.